# Android Dash Lines Not Showing

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

Just note, I did reference the creating a dash line issues here on SO and with various searches via Google... Anyway, the issue is just that. I am not able to draw dash lines via xml (Can with DashPathEffect but don't want to keep doing this). Here is the dash drawable I use (dash_line.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line">

<stroke
        android:color="@color/whiteColor"
        android:dashWidth="10dp"
        android:width="10dp"
        android:dashGap="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Now, then the implementation in xml for the imageview:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/dash_test"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="10dp"
     android:background="@drawable/dash_line"/>
```

I am working with Android API 18. I even disable Hardware Acceleration in the manifest and even on the view itself by setting the layer type (both tried in xml and programmatically). I verified by taking the view, dashView.isHardwareAccelerated() and it is false. Any thoughts as to what I am missing?

Edit:
I can draw solid lines by the way so I know its not a layering issue.

Edit:
One work around is to use PathDashEffect. Although then you get into the issue of not being able to draw on top of images (which I would need to do). So... still would like an xml solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting `software` as a `layerType` in your `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    android:layerType="software"
    ...
/>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that both in xml and programatically. Nothing.

Comment: Ok, keep this setting in xml and try wrapping your `shape` into, for instance `selector` and tell if that works.

Comment: I tried wrapping the shape into a selector but that did not work either (keeping the layerType to software).